# Elasticsearch: restore deleted index

Tags: elasticsearch, backup, elasticsearch-indices

I accidentally delete index in Elasticsearch. Unfortunatelly backup procedure was not setup :(

After some hustle with ext4magic I managed to restore files related (I hope) to deleted index:

`_data/nodes/0/indices/3pbVajZhRUClZ0reezS1CQ/`

So, now I want somehow import/open this index back into elastic. Any suggestions how I can do it?

Comment: For information: index was not restored :( I place it to corresponding directory, elastic detect it, but complain that cannot find some file (segment index or something like this). 
I try same procedure with other indices and them was restored correctly.
So, I assume ext4magic do not restore all files.